Get Path from URL in asp.net C#
I want to get the path from URL.
In local I am using Request.Url.Authority, which gives me the local path and code works fine, since the URL is localhost.
But in UAT and Production website URL is like www.xyz.com/default.
Request.Url.Authority only returns/read till www.xyz.com, and hence path is now showing when I am trying to get the image. Please tell what modification should I make in the code.
Thanks

You can try to use this statements:
string fullPath = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri; // Gives you the full URL
string path = Request.Url.AbsolutePath; // Gives you the path

